# Understanding IAM Passrole

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I couldn't understand the use of IAM Passrole. Can anyone explain with simple example?
I am referring the page : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html but couldn't make much sense out it.

Comment: A nuance missing from the existing answers: Using `Condition` to limit where the role can be passed [IAM: Pass an IAM role to a specific AWS service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_iam-passrole-service.html)

Answer (score 60):

`PassRole` is a permission granted to IAM Users and resources that permits them to use an IAM Role.

For example, imagine that there is an IAM Role called *Administrators*. This role has powerful permissions that should *not* be given to most users.

Next, imagine an IAM User who has permissions to **launch an Amazon EC2 instance**. While launching the instance, the user can specify an IAM Role to associate with the instance. If the user — who is *not* an Administrator — were to launch an EC2 instance with the *Administrators* role, then they could login to the instance and issue commands using permissions from that role. It would be a way for them to **circumvent permissions**: while not being an administrator themselves, they could assign the IAM Role to a resource, and then use that resource to gain privileged access.

To prevent this scenario, IAM requires that the user be granted the `iam:PassRole` permission for the *Administrators* role. If the user does not have that permission, then they will not be permitted to launch the EC2 instance as described, or to assign that role to any other services. **It gives them permission to *pass a role* to a service or resource.**

Comment: Let say user is granted iam:PassRole for admin role. He create EC2 instance with Admin Role. Now can he ssh to EC2 instance and do admin activity which was not allowed to user directly? If yes then how does it solves the issue?

Comment: @sanjaypatel No, you mis-read my scenario. The idea is that a non-Admin person should _not_ be given PassRole permissions for an Admin role. If they _are_given such permissions, then they can act as an Admin, which is bad.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein does it mean, when a non-admin user tries to launch an instance that requires admin role, it will throw error to not allow non admin user to launch instance?

Comment: @WaiYanHein If a user tries to launch an Amazon EC2 instance with an IAM Role and they do not have `iam:PassRole` permissions to pass that role then, yes, the launch of the instance will be denied.

Answer (score 36):

Simply,

- when the service B needs the ROLE
- A has the `iam:PassRole` permission about the ROLE,
- A can give the ROLE to B.

Answer (score 3):

This is the permission granted for a user to be allowed to pass a role to a service during configuration, without this a user can not perform that binding. You can use this permission combined with resource Arns to limit what roles the user can pass to the service

If for example you have many applications with many different available IAM roles to choose from you might want to restrict the roles a user is able to pass to the service. You would be able to limit this scope using the below statements.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:GetRole",
            "iam:PassRole"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/EC2-WordpressRole",
            "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/EC2-DatabaseRole"
        ]
    }]
}
```

In the above scenario there might also be a `arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/EC2-AdminRole` but because this role grants an EC2 host permissions this user should not be able to give to an EC2 it is withheld from the EC2 list by the person who configured the permissions.

Comment: It is clear that `PassRole is a permission granted to IAM Users and resources that permits them to use an IAM Role`;  In addition to users, Is this applicable to roles as well? Ex: RoleA can't create iam_users, RoleB can create iam_users; can we use iam:PassRole permissions to allow RoleA
 to create new iam users using perms of roleB?

Comment: Yes a role can assume another role with permissions, in fact its why external IDs exist to prevent the situation where a role in one account can hop from one account to another, when they should not have permission: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user_externalid.html.

Comment: Thank you @chris-williams , I'm trying to accomplish the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64212547/creating-iam-user-and-aws-secrets-via-iampassrole but unable to understand what I'm doing wrong. Would appreciate it if you could shed some light on it.