# creating iam user and aws secrets via iam:passrole

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have two iam roles,

- allaccessrole (with complete aws account access)
- limitedaccessrole (with very limited access to certain services only)

How do I utilize `iam:passrole` so that `limitedaccessrole` can utilize the permissions of `allaccessrole` for creating new resources(ex: a new iam user/ec2 instance)?

I added

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "iam:PassRole",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {"iam:PassedToService": "iam.amazonaws.com"}
        }
    }
]

}
```

to `limitedaccessrole` 's policy but when I try creating a new user, it still says

> `limitedaccessrole` is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateUser on resource: arn:aws:iam::myaccnumber:user/new-user-m-trying-to-create

I also tried

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "iam:PassRole",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:sts::acc_num:role/limitedaccessrole",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {"iam:PassedToService": "iam.amazonaws.com"}
        }
    }
]

}
```

This also gives me:

> limitedaccessrole is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateUser on resource: arn:aws:iam::myaccnumber:user/new-user-m-trying-to-create

In short is there a way to make `limitedaccessrole`

- create resources (a new iam user + secrets) while utilizing a combination of IAM:Passrole and
- an existing `allaccessrole` (which can do everything)
- AND without giving "iam:CreateUser" permission to the `limitedaccessrole`.

Appreciate any inputs.
EDIT: I think I have a confused understanding of what IAM Passrole does. Looks like iam passrole is to be used when you want some service to have the same permissions as a specified role, but not when you want one role to take on the permissions of another role.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `sts:AssumeRole` permission to accomplish what you're trying to achieve.

The workflow for this is below:

- Resource A has Role A. Role A has permission `sts:AssumeRole` to allow it to assume Role B.
- Resource A performs `sts:AssumeRole` to assume Role B. IAM key, secret key and session ID returned.
- Resource performs interaction using SDK/CLI specifying specifically the three values returned.

To summarise, when you assume a role you use the credentials returned to act as the role. It is not automatic, you could support many roles.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I wanted to clarify that  Right now there is only Role A (limited rights) and Role B (full rights) and No resources.  Admin has access to both roles. Role B can make policy updates to Role A and wants to incorporate/utilize `iam:PassRole`.  the idea is that anyone  While logged in as Role A  should be able to utilize RoleB permissions to create new a Resource R (ex: iam user and secrets). Would sts assume role be applicable even in this case? Why can't we use iam pass role?

Comment: `iam:PassRole` allows you to explicitly give a service the ability to use the role, it does not give your role the ability to assume it. For that you need to use STS.